# I delete django migrations, but have some errors

Tags: python, django, database

i delete all migration files

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

then drop the database and create new, clear. But when i try to create the initial migrations and generate the database schema:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

i have error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'buzz_local.api_userprofile' doesn't exist")
```

why?
i don't need any migration files, because we need to recreate current db

Comment: Deleting all migrations is almost never the right thing to do. Why have you done it?

Comment: Yeah, i know it. I need a new initial migration file without other migrations. I've do it few times on my local machine, but now i have this trouble. It's not a production

Comment: In project we need to change type of some fields and other causes...

Comment: Then you should have [squashed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) the migrations, not deleted them.

Comment: are there any data in your db ? or are you creating an new one

Comment: I think it's trouble with my local mysql, because i clone project with migrations and have the same error

Comment: @Bijoy no, i drop and create a new db

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back we too did have the same problem. If a single file inside migrations folder get deleted, it may cause havoc. We did the following :

As you have mentioned that you are creating a **new database**, what you can probabaly do is

1. Delete all files inside `migrations` folder leaving `__init__.py` file (If deleted just create a new empty file with the name `__init__.py`).

Then try `makemigrations` command. Most of the time this works, as all the migration files are regenerated.

2. If the above method doesnt work then you have to create the tables manually. Its a little hard work as you would have to manually create every fields on such table. If you dont know how to manually create (or are worried that the tables would mess up), the you can check any previous Django project's db and check what properties are given to each field of different types.

Step 2 is not so messy if you implement the procedures correctly. Like say you have defined a ImageField as  (Eg : In MySQL)

```
image = ImageField(upload_to='/pics', null=True, blank=True)
```

In database its just a VARCHAR field

`'image' varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,`

This methods worked for us in 2 of our projects, again I would say that you could try this if you are creating a new database, If working on an existing database it could be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case; I've solved the problem migrating the apps one by one. Also at one of my app, I had to comment out the central model (The model which has a lots of Foreign Keys to the other models) at the first migration then reactivate it for second migration for that app.

I'm not sure if this works with any case, but technically it should. Hope this helps.